# How would you configure a dedicated static media HTTP server?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, configuration, optimization, performance

Now that more websites are switching to a set-up with nginx in the front and Apache in the back (or a different webserver doing a better job at serving static media than Apache), I was wondering the following:

**Would it make sense to put static media on a dedicated server (running nginx), instead of running nginx in front of Apache?**

I'm not talking about budget, maintenance, etc. (I know that running 2 servers is more expensive than running 1). What I mean is:

**How would you fully optimize a *system* dedicated to serving static files?** What things can be done on the hardware and software level to optimize for static files that *can't* be done on a system that's also running Apache?

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Installing two servers instead of one should provide some advantage.

To be honest for serving static files I cannot see any advantage. For load balancing you can use either a dedicated load balancer or use DNS round robin. For fail-over you need some HA setup (see Pacemaker for more details).

So for serving static files I would take care on other elements like big bandwith of the Internet connection, fast HDD (or maybe a SDD) and more cores instead of much RAM (I wouldn't deny it). I would avoid virtualized server solutions and would take care to have sendfile installed and configured.